# Where can I find complete issuer profiles for CPA EMV applications?

Tags: emv

MChip Advance and VSDC publish complete issuer profiles for relatively broad use cases, but I cannot find similar for CPA, which seems to be structured much differently than the two (particularly with tags BF30-BF42 (or 3F30-3F42, depending on card manufacturer).

Are there, for example, closely analogous VSDC or MCHIPAdvance issuer profiles for CPA EMV applications, which make use of similar multiple profile selection, issuer options profile controls, etc., ?

If so, which are more complete when applied to CPA issuer profiles (by this I mean which has the most overlap in tags used)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it [here](https://www.emvco.com/approvals.aspx?id=105). There are two documents: CPA profiles and CCD profiles. They are used different card configuration. CPA more suitable for Visa and Mchip emulation, CCD вehaves like common EMV application.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Alexander this is pretty much as good as I could have hoped for!  This will save me alot of time in my next project!